# Link to SSRS report to directly download PDF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there a query string parameter I can pass to an SSRS report that will result in a direct download of the report (preferably in PDF) rather than having the browser navigate to the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for.

By adding the following query string to the URL, SSRS will deliver the report in PDF format rather than through the usual interface.

```
&rs:Format=PDF
```

I'm assuming that all other necessary parameters should be provided in the query string as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with a PowerShell script. The key is to pass in `&rs:Format=PDF` to the URL. [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2017)

```
#set SSRS variables
$exportPath = 'C:\Temp\';
$ssrsPath = 'http://YourReportServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fYour%20Report%20Folder/Your%20%20Report';
$ssrsFileName = $ssrsPath.split('/')[-1] -replace '%20', ' ';
$ssrsFile = $exportPath + $ssrsFileName + '.pdf';

#remove file if it already exists
if (Test-Path $ssrsFile) 
{
    Remove-Item $ssrsFile
}

#create pdf of SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report
$ssrsFilePdf = $ssrsPath + '&rs:Format=PDF'
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ssrsFilePdf -OutFile $ssrsFile -UseDefaultCredentials -TimeoutSec 240);
```